# Added a bone to a skeleton then applied automatic weights, now my mesh is bigger than my skeleton

Tags: rigging

Added a bone to a skeleton then applied automatic weights, now my mesh is bigger than my skeleton.

I tried everything to fix this. Any tips? I'm a beginner with Blender.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is. Bones are made to animate a mesh, whatever it looks like, so, if you're animating a human form, it seems quite normal that your mesh would be bigger than your bones. Unless I missed something?

Comment: i only thought it was wrong becuse im getting alot of errors when i import it in too unreal engine?  Here are the errors. http://prntscr.com/lyu1xl